# django patch method to edit or update the user fields

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

i am using django and rest framework, I am unable to update the data(fields) from the PATCH method.If i click, every time its creating the new record.
please find the code below;

data from postman:method - PATCH

```
{
    "company_id": 2,
    "company_code": "PR",
    "company_name": "Padise",
    "company_description": "company",
    "company_address": "company",
    "active": true,
    "updated_by": null,
    "updated_dtm": "2017-04-26T12:12:20Z"
}
```

above data "company_id" is the primary key,i need to edit or update the record with the primary key.
In PATCH method where i need to pass the primary key for edit or update the record.

views.py

```
class getCompanyDetails(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        comp = company.objects.filter(active = True)
        serializer = restGetCompanySerializer(comp, many=True)
        return JsonResponse({"allCompanies":serializer.data})

    def patch(self, request):
        serializer = restAddCompanySerializer(data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializer.py

```
class restAddCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = company
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a model instance to update. Try something like:

```
class getCompanyDetails(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        comp = company.objects.filter(active = True)
        serializer = restGetCompanySerializer(comp, many=True)
        return JsonResponse({"allCompanies":serializer.data})

    def patch(self, request):
        # fetching company with given company_id
        company = company.objects.get(pk=request.data['company_id'])
        # passing company as first argument. This will invoke 
        #  ModelSerializer's 'update' method instead of 'create' method.
        serializer = restAddCompanySerializer(company, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help.Its working fine.But updated_dtm is not taking the date time from the models`updated_dtm=models.DateTimeField(null = True,default=datetime.now)` its not updating the field in database.How to fix this?.

Comment: I don't understand your concern. If what you want is to update `update_dtm` every time you update an instance, just make an edit models.py as: `updated_dtm = models.DateTimeField(null=True, auto_now_add=True)`.

Comment: @user1335606 does this solve your issue? If it helps, please upvote  :)